# codeigniter form prepopulation

Tags: codeigniter, post, input

Is there a method to prepopulate a certain field in a form using data from the previous page using codeigniter.

I have a page with input fields that are filled out, if the user presses a "add" button they are given a new form with similar fields.  I want those fields to be populated from data received by the previous page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you simply use the $_POST data to display the second form?

Answer (score 1):

You can use CI's form helper function [set_value()](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html) which uses the $_POST and may save you some code testing if the $_POST value is empty because you can specify a default value if not set. Should be using this anyway if your using CI's form validation.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the data entered in form 1 in sessions or in the database and display it in the second form. Or as mentioned use `$_POST` in the second form to retrieve submitted data from the previous.